# How to use public methods from other ASP.NET Core controller in solution?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I am programming a Web API using ASP.NET Core in connection with a web application. I am looking for a way to call a method (for example `methodCallableFromOtherControllers`) from another controller without it being callable from the client (vus.js). Thanks in advance for the support!

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("get_test")]
    public string get_test([FromBody] Test test) 
    {

    }

    public string methodCallableFromOtherControllers() 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to create an interface and write the implement which contains the same feature of the target controller?

Comment: could you show it with a code example?

Comment: How is it going on sir? If you feel my post is helpful to you, could you pls accept it as the answer? And pls point it out if I misunderstood in some place, thanks for your reply in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Pls allow me to add my ideas here to describe it clearly.

Let's assume that there're 2 controllers here: `HomeController` and `HelloController`

And this is my HelloController:

```
namespace WebApi_net5.Controllers
{
    public class HelloController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("getHello")]
        public string Index()
        {
            return "hello";
        }
    }
}
```

If I wanna call this `Index()` method from HomeController, I provide these 2 ways:

```
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("test")]
        public string test() {
            var controller = new HelloController();
            string temp = controller.Index();
            return "a"+ temp;
        }
    }
```

Or using `AddControllersAsServices()` in startup.cs

```
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        private HelloController _controller;
        public HomeController(HelloController controller) {
            _controller = controller;
        }

        [HttpGet("test")]
        public string test() {
            string temp = _controller.Index();
            return "a"+ temp;
        }
    }
```

startup.cs ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.AddControllers();
            services.AddControllers().AddControllersAsServices();
        }
```